# Gmail APIの制限について質問です。

Tags: google-api, gmail

Gmail APIの制限について質問です。

下記のURLのDaily Usage Quotaについて、これは全ユーザーを合わせた制限値でしょうか。
この制限を緩和する方法はないでしょうか？
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota

現在、複数のBussiness企業向けにGmail APIを使ったサービスを開発しており
想定の総ユーザー数が多くなった時に超えてしまう懸念があり、このような質問をしています。

また、お客様ごとに異なるClientを作成して制限数を回避することは可能でしょうか。
その際、OAuth Developer Verificationは、Clientごとに必要になりますか。
https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification

Comment: はじめまして。
私も現在この件に関して疑問を持っています。
もしよかったら何かお分かりになったことがあれば、
共有していただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 英語版の方で同様の質問をしてみています。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901501/daily-usage-quota-is-a-per-project-limit